# How do I get a web part to refresh in IE?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I have a SharePoint web part that gets XML data from an .ASHX page, parses it and displays it using JavaScript.  Everything works fine, until the XML changes.  When I view the web part in IE, the new data is not updated until I close the browser.  Even doing a CTRL-F5 does not grab the new data.

Firefox displays the new data immediately, with just a simple page refresh.

I have added a timestamp to the query string of my .ASHX page so that the XML result is not cached, but that did not fix my IE woes.  Any other ideas?

**Edit**
The .ASHX page is using the API to access a list and is building the XML string, then returning that as an `application/XML` content type.  I have confirmed that the XML is updated to reflect the new data in the list.  I am also able to see the data consumed in the web part when it is displayed in FireFox.

**Solution**
I actually was generating the timestamp to append to my query in the server code, and then putting that string in the javascript.  Once I moved the timestamp code to the javascript, things started working much better.

Comment: Is your call to the .ashx page a POST or a GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely cached, there's no other logical explanation why it would work in Firefox and not in IE. Try reloading IE several times in a row.

Check what headers that .ashx page sets.

It's not just your browser which could be caching the page, any middleware including web server might have a flawed caching implementation.  You can also try using HTTP POST instead of GET because according to HTTP specification, POST requests should never be cached.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a custom Web Part or one of the out-of-the-box Web Parts? It would make it easier to help you if you provided any more information on how you're retrieving the data from the HttpHandler (ashx).

Comment: it's a custom web part.  The ASHX steps through a SharePoint list  using the API and builds some custom XML to be consumed by my web part.